# Octave + Gnuplot rendering image upside down

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I am displaying data using function imagesc(). If I set fltk as graphics_toolkit image is displayed correctly.

Can't post images directly(low reputation) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARiwF.png

If I use gnuplot as plotting program image is rendered upside down. 
fltk is unusable for me because its window isn't responding while function in octave is running. I also tried plot sine and it was correct plotted through fltk and gnuplot too.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two workarounds:

- Use `axis("xy")` or `axis("ij")` to control the orientation of the y-axis, as decribed in the [`axis` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axis-Configuration.html)
- Use `set(gca, "ydir", "normal")` or  `set(gca, "ydir", "reverse")`, as decribed in the [axes properties doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axes-Properties.html)